# Show that the function $F(x) =(x-a)^2 (x-b)^2 +x$ has the value $(a+b)/2$ at some point $x$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

> Show that the function $$F(x) =(x-a)^2 (x-b)^2 +x$$ has the value $\frac{a + b}{2}$ at some point $x$.

I think it might be something with the the intermediate-value theorem, not sure though. anyone have any idea about how to go about this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint**:

$$F(a) = a \quad\quad F(b) = b$$

and $(a + b) / 2$ is the average of $a$ and $b$, and so between them.